# Про ComponentDidMount/DidUpdate и отрисовку в браузере

Tags: reactjs

В документации React к useEffect написано:

> Unlike componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, the function passed to useEffect fires after layout and paint, during a deferred event.

componentDidMount/DidUpdate вызывается после рендера и монтирования компонента. Я всегда думал, что если компонент смонтирован, то он и отрисован в брузере.
В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Действительно ли, что вызов метода render и монтирование компонента в dom-дерево не гарантирует отрисовку его в браузере ? Если так, то в какой момент браузер "решает" перерисовать dom-дерево ?
2. Блокирует ли componentDidMount/DidUpdate отрисовку браузера (т.е останавливает ее) или он ее просто замедляет ?
3. Если componentDidMount/DidUpdate вызывает ДО отрисовки браузера, тогда почему в самом методе componentDidMount/DidUpdate мы можем получить (через ref или через querySelector) dom-узел и все его свойства, включая размеры, отступы и т.д. ? При этом все свойства будут правильные и точные. Откуда он их берет, если сам dom-узел еще не отрисован.

Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на Ваши вопросы:

> Действительно ли, что вызов метода render и монтирование компонента в
> dom-дерево не гарантирует отрисовку его в браузере? Если так, то в
> какой момент браузер "решает" перерисовать dom-дерево?

В при вызове метода render React запускает процесс перерисовки, модифицируя документ и/или его конкретный(ые) элемент(ы). Далее браузер реагирует на эти изменения и превращает эти изменения в то что пользователь видит на экране.

Используя [WEB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) браузер сообщает слушателям о своем "состоянии", благодаря чему React может понять что событие render'a "произошло".

Однако это означает только то что само DOM дерево было обновлено, а процессы перерисовки запущены, но не то что пользователь гарантировано увидит полностью готовый для потребления контент.

Например, если мы попытаемся получить offset-размеры какого либо элемента привязавшись к [ComponetDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) или [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) то можем получить 0, просто из за того что еще не все стили были применены.

> Блокирует ли componentDidMount / DidUpdate отрисовку браузера (т.е
> останавливает ее) или он ее просто замедляет?

Нет, и нет.

> Если componentDidMount/DidUpdate вызывает ДО отрисовки браузера, тогда
> почему в самом методе componentDidMount / DidUpdate мы можем получить
> (через ref или через querySelector) dom-узел и все его свойства,
> включая размеры, отступы и т.д.? При этом все свойства будут
> правильные и точные. Откуда он их берет, если сам dom-узел еще не
> отрисован.

(ответил выше)

Мы можем быть уверены что получим полностью готовый DOM если привяжемся к `componentDidMount` или `useEffect`. Это даст нам правильные привязки `ref` и корректную работу методов аналогичных [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Вообше не согласен.Даже в доках написано что componentDidMount  <<вызовет дополнительный рендер перед тем, как браузер обновит экран>> .Если там вызвать `setstate` конечно.